# Decrease in data transmission speed between R and SQL Server AzureVM

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, rodbc

We have two virtual machines in Azure, first one with Ubuntu 18.04 and RStudio and the second one with a SQL Server 2017 instance. Both VM are "Standard H8m", are in the same Azure subscription and their connection are pinned as Azure recommend us.

Every month we execute a sort of ETLs in our R machine that connect to SQL Server with RODBC library and FreeTDS driver and make some queries to obtain data.

Usually, each query takes <5 minutes and brings about 5 million rows (with just 2 columns). However, this month the queries are taking about 5 times more each one, and that is making our ETLs execution unacceptable.

The queries are not computationally complex:

```
select b.ColumnOne, a.ColumnTwo
from TableOne a, TableTwo b
where b.Date = 201809
  and a.TableOrigin = "TableTwo"
```

TableOne has 2000 rows and TableTwo is partitioned by "Date" column, with 30 dates and 2.000.000.000 rows for each one.

When we execute one of those queries in Management Studio, it takes about 10 seconds to show all the results, so we assume that the delay is produced by network connection, no by computational cost. Nevertheless, we don't know why this month the data transmission speed has been decreased so much.

When we execute one of those queries from R machine, at the ManagementStudio Monitor we can't see any database I/O (the graphic stay at 0.1 MB/sec). This is weird for us, because it has to read a lot of rows and, mainly, because we remember that other months the query start its execution reading at >200MB/sec the first seconds.

We are confident that in this month we don't have made any update or change in R library or driver.

So the question is, has there been any change or update in SQL Server 2017 that can affects the way SQL Server plan remote queries? If not, we don't know what the delay may be due, so we're open to any suggestion.

Comment: One query --> multiple **queries** (not "querys" ....)

Comment: @marc_s thanks and sorry for the mistakes! I have to improve my english and my knowledges about Stackoverflow nomenclature...